# URL with parameter leeds to 404

Tags: overrides, url-rewrite, parameter

I've created a module that has frontend page. I want to pass parameters to that page.
When i enter http://mydomain.com/news  - it shows me my page but when i cal http://mydomain.com/news/id/1 - it shows 404 error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your module uses the default routing system of magento `{module}/{controller}/{action}`, it doesn't work in your case because Magento is looking for the class named `IdController` and the method `1Action` (this can not even exist).

if the controller name and/or action name are missing Magento uses `index` for them.

And since the url `/news/` works, I assume it is handled by the `indexAction` from the `IndexController`.

If you want to pass parameters you have 2 options:

**Option 1**
Pass them as simple `GET` parameters: `/news/?id=1`.

**Option 2**
Use the full action url: `/news/index/index/id/1`.